# @using and <%using difference

Tags: asp.net, razor, knockout-2.0, kentico, knockout-mvc

I'm a fan of Razor & Knockout mvc & MVC,

unfortunately, we just cannot use plain MVC on our CMS(KENTICO) Solution, so I had to create a custom MVC with ASP .NET with classic ASPX.

by following a simple tutorial: http://knockoutmvc.com/BetterList

just a question, is this Razor syntax:

```
@using (var item = ko.Foreach(x => x.AllItems))
{
 <li>
  @item.Html.Span(x => x.FullName)                    
 </li>
}
```

equivalent to this ASPX syntax:

```
<%using (var item = ko.Foreach(x => x.AllItems))
 { %>
  <li>
   <%= item.Html.Span(x => x.FullName) %>
  </li>
 <%} %>
```

?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two code blocks are almost functionally equivalent.

You need to change the output from `<%=` to `<%:` (if using .NET 4.0 and above), as this adds HTML encoding to the output.

Comment: this is a good tip, but I'm still not getting the equivalent of "razor" using, I'm getting a knockout error on the aspx one

Comment: Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: FullName is not defined;
Bindings value: text : FullName

Comment: if the two code blocks are equivalent, the bug must be in the Knockout MVC that is not fully supported for ASPX :(

Comment: ok Thanks you, at least I've excluded the syntax, I'll investigate on knockout MVC now :)